# Last post not in recent inbox messages

Tags: support

My last post does not show up in my recent inbox messages.

But it does show up in a search.

Does it only show up if it has had replies?

Comment: You only get notifications if someone interacts with your post, for example, comments or answers. Otherwise the best place to find them is https://askubuntu.com/users/573838/fixit7

Comment: by "last post" do you mean this?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061084/brisk-menu-has-quit-running-unexpectedly

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes.

Answer (score 6):

If by "last post" you mean [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061084/brisk-menu-has-quit-running-unexpectedly), then you won't see anything in your inbox about this post unless you get replies to it or some other type of interaction (comments, answers, proposed edits, etc.).

New posts made by yourself won't show up in your inbox until some trigger happens to make a message in your inbox, and such triggers are typically the things I just stated (new comments on it, new answers, new proposed edits to the question, etc.).